# MVC Telerik Grid w/ dynamic data: How to pass column type information to the grid

Tags: model-view-controller, dynamic, grid, telerik

in my Telerik MVC-Grid, I'm using dynamic binding with datatable. Everything works fine except the filtering, the operator dropdown remains empty. I guess that the grid doesn't know what kind of filter to apply because no type is given. But if I know the type of the column, how could I pass this information from the controller to the view?

I posted a sample project [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/filtering-when-using-binding-with-datatable.aspx).

Regards
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the answer from the Telerik Team, and it works :) I will mark this as answer when I am allowed (in 7 hours :-))

> In order to set column types in your scenario, you should upgrade to
>   the Q3 2011 version of the Telerik Extension for ASP.NET MVC. In this
>   version we have added MemberType setting to GridColumnSettings feature
>   which used in the provided sample.
>
> ```
> new GridColumnSettings { Member = "Number", Title="Number", MemberType= typeof(int) }
> ```
>
> Regards, Rosen the Telerik team

Link to the thread: [click](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/filtering-when-using-binding-with-datatable.aspx)